# The dplyr way to get grouped differences

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to figure out the dplyr way to do grouped differences.

Here is some fake data:

```
>crossing(year=seq(1,4),week=seq(1,3)) %>% 
  mutate(value = c(rep(4,3),rep(3,3),rep(2,3),rep(1,3)))

    year  week value
   <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     1     1     4
 2     1     2     4
 3     1     3     4
 4     2     1     3
 5     2     2     3
 6     2     3     3
 7     3     1     2
 8     3     2     2
 9     3     3     2
10     4     1     1
11     4     2     1
12     4     3     1
```

What I would like is year 1- year2, year2-year3, and year3-year4. The result would like like the following.

```
    year  week diffs
   <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1
 2     1     2     1
 3     1     3     1
 4     2     1     1
 5     2     2     1
 6     2     3     1
 7     3     1     1
 8     3     2     1
 9     3     3     1
```

Edit:

I apologize. I was trying to make a simple reprex, but I messed up a lot.

Please let me know what the proper etiquette is. I don't want to ruffle any feathers.

1. I did not know that `-diff()` was a function. What I am actually looking for is percent difference ((new-old)/old)*100 and I am not able to find a straight forward way to use `diff` to get that value.
2. I am starting from the largest year. Adding a `arrange(desc(year))` to the above code is what I have. I would be trimming the smallest `year` not the largest.

If this edit with worth a separate question let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have missing years for each week:

```
df %>% 
    arrange(year) %>%
    group_by(week) %>% 
    mutate(diffs = value - lead(value)) %>% 
    na.omit() %>% select(-value)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   week [3]
#   year  week diffs
#  <int> <int> <dbl>
#1     1     1     1
#2     1     2     1
#3     1     3     1
#4     2     1     1
#5     2     2     1
#6     2     3     1
#7     3     1     1
#8     3     2     1
#9     3     3     1
```

Comment: After my edit I was able to change you code slightly to get what I was looking for. Thanks for bringing up `lead` I never heard of that command before. Very Useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `diff`, but it needs adjusting, as it subtracts the other way and returns a vector that's one shorter than what it's passed:

```r
library(tidyverse)

diffed <- crossing(year = seq(1,4), 
                   week = seq(1,3)) %>% 
    mutate(value = rep(4:1, each = 3)) %>% 
    group_by(week) %>% 
    mutate(value = c(-diff(value), NA)) %>% 
    drop_na(value)

diffed
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   week [3]
#>    year  week value
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     1
#> 2     1     2     1
#> 3     1     3     1
#> 4     2     1     1
#> 5     2     2     1
#> 6     2     3     1
#> 7     3     1     1
#> 8     3     2     1
#> 9     3     3     1
```

Answer (score 0):

using `dplyr` and `do`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(week) %>% do(cbind(.[-nrow(.),1:2],diffs=-diff(.$value)))

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
# # Groups:   week [3]
#    year  week diffs
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     2     1     1
# 3     3     1     1
# 4     1     2     1
# 5     2     2     1
# 6     3     2     1
# 7     1     3     1
# 8     2     3     1
# 9     3     3     1
```